# Matching and Perfect Math

Tags: java, c, algorithm, graph

From Skiena's book, This is not HW, and merely my preparation for an interview.

Given this question,

A matching of an undirected graph G = (V, E) is a set of edges no two of which have a vertex in common. A perfect matching is a matching in which all vertices are matched.

(a) Construct a graph G with 2n vertices and n^2 edges such that G has an an expo- nential number of perfect matchings.

(b) Construct a graph G with 2n vertices and n^2 edges such that G has exactly one unique perfect matching.

I just have no idea how to begin. For a, I chose n = 3, so I now know I have 6 vertices and 9 edges, and tried connecting them, but I didn't know if it was perfect matching.

Comment: No undirected graph can have n^2 edges; is n^2 what you mean when you write n2? A clique has (n^2-n)/2 edges. This must be talking about multigraphs then. Also, in what variable is the number of perfect matchings in (a) supposed to be exponential?

Comment: @G.Bach I mean N^2, it says to construct a graph with 2n edges, and n^2 edges

Comment: It must be talking about non-simple graphs then, and probably multigraphs, because even a complete directed graph with self loops has only n^2 edges.

Comment: @G.Bach it doesn't specify, what I've posted is what the question is, and I couldn't solve it.

Comment: @G.Bach: There are twice as many vertices as you think.

Comment: Do you want me to give you the answer, or do you want a hint?  I don't know if I can give a hint that would do any good, but I can certainly give you the answer

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot Answer would help, I give up. :( I tried I guess

Comment: @tmyklebu Oh I misread, you're right. That means a clique has 2n^2-n edges, which of course changes everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For a): take a complete bipartite graph over 2n vertices with both partitions having n vertices each. These graphs have n! perfect matchings, which is more than 2^n for n > 2.
2. For b): We build something similar to a complete bipartite graph over (n,n) vertices. Call the partitions A=(1,2,3,...,n) and B=(n+1,n+2,n+3,...2n).

   Make A a clique.

   For every vertex n+i in B, add an edge (n+i,j) for every vertex j in A with j<=i. For example, vertex n+1 only is incident to the edge (n+1,1); the vertex n+2 is incident to (n+2, 1) and (n+2,2); the vertex n+3 is incident to (n+3,1) (n+3,2) (n+3,3).

   This forces the unique perfect matching to be {e in E | e = (n+i,i) for some i in [1;n]} (try to prove this to practice induction).

   Since A is a clique over n vertices, it has n^2/2 - n/2 edges. The edges running between A and B are a total of `sum from 1 to n` which is n^2/2 + n/2, so together we get
   n^2/2 - n/2 + n^2/2 + n/2 = n^2 edges.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this graph will help you for (a):

V={1,2,a,b}

E={(1,a),(1,b),(2,a),(2,b)}

2*2 vertices

2^2 edges